# Rails Order Model By Nested Attributes in JSONB field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have a `Campaign` model that has a conversion rate listed like this:

`campaign.quota_data["raw_quota_data"][0]["Conversion"] = 33`

I'd like to do something like

```
Campaign.all.order(quota_data["raw_quota_data"][0]["Conversion"])
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Edit: example of what the `quota_data` data structure looks like:

```
{"raw_quota_data"=>
  [
    {"QuotaCPI"=>1.5, "Questions"=>nil, "Conversion"=>0, "SurveyQuotaID"=>4205891, "SurveyQuotaType"=>"Total", "OverQuotaThreshold"=>true}
  ],
  "available_quotas"=>[{"id"=>4205891, "cpi"=>1.0499999999999998, "name"=>"Total", "traits"=>{}, "available"=>400, "conversion"=>0}],
  "rejectable_trait_groups"=>[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically trying to do a in memory sort after fetching data from database. You could just use `array.sort` or `array.sort_by`

```
Campaign.all.sort_by {|c| c.quota_data["raw_quota_data"][0]["Conversion"]}}
```

Comment: This got me along the right track. I ended up wanting to sort them in descending order so I went with `atc = atc.sort {|a,b| b.quota_data["raw_quota_data"][0]["Conversion"] <=> a.quota_data["raw_quota_data"][0]["Conversion"]}`

Comment: probably Campaign.all.sort_by {|c| -c.quota_data["raw_quota_data"][0]["Conversion"]}} would have worked.. just a minus sign for the value ;)